# Como usar "objects.filter" selecionando somente o usuário logado na aplicação?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estou usando a autenticação do django e nos templates HTML funciona muito bem quando eu uso por exemplo:

```
{% if user.is_anonymous %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Gostaria de usar esse mesmo "user", que se refere ao usuário logado, para fazer um select no momento de carregar uma view.

Como estou tentando fazer:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tabelas'] = Tabela.objects.filter(**usuario=user.id**)
        return context
```

Gostaria de pegar id do usuário logado que tem uma ForeignKey com **Tabela** e assim selecionar somente os dados que importam. Mas ocorre o erro:

```
NameError at /
name 'user' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'user' is not defined
```

Alguém sabe como eu faço para usar o usuário logado nesse trecho ?

Answer (score 1):

Fuçando um pouco e enchendo o código de print(), descobri uma maneira de fazer, segue:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        req_user_pk = context["view"].request.user.pk
        context['tabelas'] = Tabela.objects.filter(usuario=req_user_pk)
        #context['tabelas'] = Tabela.objects.order_by('id')
        return context
```

Se alguém tem uma sugestão melhor, sou todo ouvidos :)